# "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds" in R-programming

Tags: r, remote-sensing

I am trying to apply Radiometric correction to Landsat image in R.
I tried with the following code and got the error.

```
metadata <- readMeta("LT05_L1TP_141041_20110129_20161010_01_T1_MTL.txt")
TM5_RadParameters <- metadata$CALRAD
TM5_RadParameters
rad_TM5_pre <- radCor(TM5_RadParameters, metaData =  metadata, method = "rad")
rad_TM5_pre
```

ERROR

> rad_TM5_pre <- radCor(TM5_RadParameters, metaData =  metadata, method = "rad")
>   Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Your question needs additional information to be reproducible. Especially which libraries you are using.

Comment: I used RSToolbox package while preprocessing the landsat image.